# Passing a variable to another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I asked a question a while back about how to get the current variable in a loop and I got the solution :

```
    for (i in ...)
        {
        ...
          href:"javascript:on_click('+i+');"...}
```

When i run this, the loop is sending the on_click function the string 'i' instead of the value of i.

 Am I using the `+variable+` wrong? Can someone explain in more detail what wrapping a variable in + means and why it is not working in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
href:"javascript:on_click('" + i + "');"
```

Comment: YESSS thank you so much! I've been trying to figure this out for so longggg. Could you explain why this works?

Comment: Look at this tutorial: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html pretty neat code examples there, that should give you the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are - if you start a string with `"`, you have to end it with `"` (and vice versa for `'`), too. The syntax highlighting here at SO demonstrates this quite well too.

```
 href:"javascript:on_click("+i+");"...}
```

(What is happening is that `'` **within** a string surrounded by `"` is treated as regular `'` character, it does not start nor end a string literal here).

Comment: what is it called when i do `+i+`? I'd like to look up more information on it except I don't know what to search up

Comment: What happens is that `i` is converted to a string and concatenated to the surrounding strings.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you are missing double quotes to close your string. Javascript doesn't do variable interpolation in a quoted string.

Try:

```
href:"javascript:on_click('" + i + "');"...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing your quote marks.

It should be:

```
href: "javascript:on_click('" + i + "');"
```

Note how the double quotes are necessary at both ends of the invariant parts.